# Как сделать чтобы условие сработывало?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, не могу найти ошибку свою. Есть проверка на введенные данные в input формы регистрации, надо чтобы после условия, когда введена правильна почта срабатывала return true и дальше срабатывает переход в админку(страница). Сейчас условия работает, но при return true перехода нет. Спасибо заранее.

```js
//email
const submit = document.querySelector('.modal-cover__btn');
const form = document.querySelector('.modal-form');
const pattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
    let email = document.querySelector('.modal-cover__email');
    let email_value = document.querySelector('.modal-cover__email').value;
        if (email_value.match(pattern)) {
          email.classList.remove('valid');
          alert('You have entered an invalid email address!');
          return true;
        } else {
          email.classList.add('valid');
          alert('Bad email');
          return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: А что значит " переход в админку."?  то есть всё же должен сработать submit?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да совершенно верно дальше срабатывает header ("Location: https://); Но сейчас при правильном вводе return true отрабатывает и блочит переход.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под "переход в админку" имеется в виду, что должен `submit` всё же сработать, тогда надо `event.preventDefault();` переместить в условие, когда email неправильный, а `return true;` и `return false;`  удалить за ненадобностью

Кстати, при таком варианте и строки

```
email.classList.remove('valid');
alert('You have entered an invalid email address!');
```

не нужны. Всё равно страница будет перезагружаться. Можно будет упростить:

```
if (!email_value.match(pattern)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    email.classList.add('valid');
    alert('Bad email');        
}
```

Comment: Если убираю event.preventDefault(); и return true, то при не правильном вводе почты сразу идет переход на страницу, а надо чтобы блочилось, а когда правильно ввел человек почту, тогда шёл переход на старницу.

Comment: он не может переходить на другую страницу, т.к. идёт выполнение кода последовательно и пока не обработается последняя строчка в блоке кода - никто никуда не должен отправлять ничего..... и, как следствие, если почта неправильная - будет return false...... значит условие у вас просто не срабаывает

Comment: Сейчас подумаю ещё вариант))

Comment: Я попробывал ваш вариант, не работает. if (email_value.match(pattern)) {
          email.classList.remove('valid');
          return true;
        } else {
          email.classList.add('valid');
          return false;
      } Это тоже самое, что и вы предлогаете только без не !. Но не блочится переход, мне кажется дело в функции потому что при возврате return true не приходит заначение или вызов нужен, чтобы сработал переход header ("Location: https://);  и данные отправились в БД,

Comment: Исправил ответ..... похоже return false работает только если событие вызывается через инлайн обработчик. Поэтому просто надо переместить `event.preventDefault();` в другое место

Comment: Спасибо все работает, вы гений ! Вы меня не раз спасали с вопросами, спасибо большое !